# How to expire a access token in ouath2

Tags: oauth-2.0, access-token

I have currently came across OAuth2 , and I found it quite interesting, so I decided to use it in my application. The question that I face when implementing it were

1. should I use a database to save and lookup access token and see if they're expired
2. what could be the possible data model for it
3. if not, how can I expire an access token that already been issued

I'll appreciate any help

Answer (score 1):

First, an access token is issued for a limited period only. You can purge your database when it expired (it means you need at lest store that expiration time and the access token value).

During the lifecycle of the access token, clients or the authorization server may decide to revoke tokens (see the [RFC7009](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7009)).